# Relational database - adding products

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the following situation, namely I need to make a database,
in which I will store products that the user added to breakfast,
lunch, midday meal and dinner ON A SPECIFIC DAY.

I have a problem with the construction of such a relational database.
I currently have this combination of two tables:

[image]

It seems to me that I need 3 tables here in which
the products themselves will be placed, but I have no idea how
I can combine these 3 tables to get queries
products depending on the type of meal (breakfast, lunch ..) and date (the day they were added)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should have a `Products` table that should have the 5 last columns you are showing in your second table (`Orders`?). And remove them from the `Orders` table such that it only has the IDs referencing the `Meal` and `Product` and the `Date`.

Then you can do the following:

```sql
    SELECT o.Date, m.Meal_Name, p.Product_Name, p.Carbohydrates,
     p.Protein, p.Fat, p.Calories
    FROM Orders o 
    INNER JOIN Meals m ON o.MealID = m.MealID
    INNER JOIN Products p ON o.ProductID = p.ProductID
    ORDER BY o.date, m.Meal_Name, p.Product_Name
```

Note that this will allow you to easly change the parameters (such as `fat` or `Carbohydrates` for a `Product` and have it appear in all records for that product.

Answer (score 1):

While there is certainly plenty of room to interpretation here and you may only want to go so far in normalizing your data, I think a better option would be:

meals:

```
id | user_id | category_id | date
1  | 1       | 1           | 2019-09-03
```

meal_category

```
id | name
1  | breakfast
2  | lunch
3  | dinner
```

products

```
id | name | carbs | protein | fat | calories
1  | apple| 10    | 5       | 0   | 30
2  | cat  | 0     | 20      | 5   | 80
3  | ham  | 10    | 30      | 10  | 160
```

meal_products

```
meal_id | product_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
```

Bringing this together:

```
SELECT meals.id, meals.user_id, meal.date, meal_category.name, product.name, product.carbs, products.protein, products.fat, products.calories
FROM meals
   INNER JOIN meal_category ON meals.category_id = meal_category.id
   INNER JOIN meal_produts ON meals.id = meal_products.meal_id
   INNER JOIN products ON meal_products.product_id = products.id
```

Which would yeild

```
+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
| meals.id, | meals.user_id, | meal.date, | meal_category.name, | product.name, | product.carbs, | products.protein, | products.fat, | products.calories |
+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
|         1 |              1 | 9/3/2019   | breakfast           | apple         |             10 |                 5 |             0 |                30 |
|         1 |              1 | 9/3/2019   | breakfast           | cat           |              0 |                20 |             5 |                80 |
+-----------+----------------+------------+---------------------+---------------+----------------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I'm sitting here eating a brownie and I couldn't think of a food item to add to the list. "Brownie" would have been the obvious choice, but `cat` popped in first.

Comment: I must honestly admit that I am dealing for the first time
with such an extensive relational database, that's why I would be very grateful
for answering the following questions:I understand everything that is related to the products table and meal_category, but ...
1) What's hidden in the meal_id column in the meal_products table? What is she responsible for?
Because product_id refers to a product that is in the products table.
2) I don't understand what the user_id column is in the meals table, does it have to be?

Comment: 3) Suppose I want to add 100g chicken breast to dinner on September 10, 2019, where
kcal = 98 protein = 21.5g fat = 1.3g carbohydrates = 0
What would such a query look like using INSERT?

4) Suppose I would like to receive all the products from the dinner on September 10.
What would such a query look like?

5) Suppose I want to modify the macronutrient value of the added product
from dinner on September 10, 2019, what would such a query look like?
Thank you in advance for any help because I will be able to do the same and learn from it conclusions

Comment: 1) This is just a guess about your actual data. It seems like a user makes a "meal" and a "meal" is on a particular day. So the `meal_id` is just an incrementing integer that is unique for that meal for that day (breakfast on thursday, for instance). This is created in the `meal` table and is then referenced in the relationship table `meal_products` which holds the 1:many relationship between a meal and a product. This breaks up your initial thought of a `meal` being `breakfast on thursday` or `lunch on monday` to just be an id where `lunch` and `thursday` are attributes `category` and `date`

Comment: 2) This, again, was an assumption that a `user` makes a `meal`. To track which user made the meal I added the user's id as an attribute of the `meals` table. Again... if you don't have such a concept in your model, then omit that column. My assumption was that you have a table you haven't shared here to track users like `user_id | username | firstname | lastname | other attributes`.

Comment: 3) You would need to insure that `chicken breast` is in `products` table by adding it to get a `product_id`. `INSERT INTO products VALUES (4, 'Chicken Breast' , 0, 21.5g, 1.3g, 98)` for instance. Then insure that you have a meal already for `dinner on sept 10, 2019`. If not then do that INSERT `INSERT INTO meals (id, category_id, date) VALUES (2, 3, '2019-09-10');`. Finally now that you have a meal and the product you can add the relationship `INSERT INTO meal_products VALUES (4, 2);`

Comment: Ideally you would have defined these `id` columns in sqlite as `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` so that they are auto-incrementing. When you insert every other column like `INSERT INTO meals (category_id, date) VALUES ('3`, '2019-09-10');` it will insert and the `id` will generate automatically as the next available integer for that table. You can then use that new `id` when inserting downstream into `meal_products` (for instance).

Comment: Ultimately the idea here is that you have each object defined as it's own table, as well as any relationship between those objects. So here we have a `meal`, `product`, and `category` (of a meal). Then the 1:many relationship between a `meal ` and a `product` is held in your relationship/junction table `meal_products`. This is a pretty well-worn normalized design for a database and it should map well to your application that is sitting on top of the database.